# Не работает html атрибут download из за разности сервера и клиента

Tags: node.js, angular

Клиент по адресу localhost:4200 - angular7, сервер localhost:8800 nodejs.

При нажатии на ссылку href="http://localhost:8800/a8c9f8df0sdf77sdf.doc" download="Документ.doc", файл всё равно скачивается как a8c9f8df0sdf77sdf.doc, а если формат. например, jpeg, то открывается во вкладке. Как правильно в данном случае реализовать скачивание с нужным именем?

Comment: Браузер-то какой?

Comment: Пробовал сhrome, mozilla, сhromium. Но приложение в целом ориентировано на хромо-подобные браузеры